# Creating stored procedure in MySQL-8

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-8.0

I am trying to create a SP which will run batch update on about 100 million rows in a table. I created the below SP for it:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE `bulk_update`(IN table_name varchar(30))
BEGIN
DECLARE rows INT;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SET rows = 1;
WHILE rows > 0
do
SET autocommit=1;
SET @query =CONCAT('update ',table_name,' set is_summarized="N";');
PREPARE update_stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE update_stmt;
SET rows = row_count();
select sleep(1); 
commit;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE update_stmt;
END WHILE;
END //
```

It gives below error >>

```
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rows INT;
    SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SET rows = 1;
' at line 3
```

Strange part is that I am able to create the SP in MySQL-5.6, but it fails in MySQL-8 only. Can someone point me to what I am missing? Thank you

Comment: Do not use reserved words as variable names...

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. I didnt understand why it was not shown as error in mysql-5.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Either* use `autocommit=1` throughout, *or* use `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

And, once set, you do not need to set `autocommit` again.

So, get rid of `COMMIT` and move the `SET` out of the loop.

Is some other process changing the value of `is_summarized` while this proc is sleeping?  I doubt if your technique will catch all edge cases correctly.

Instead of using a declared `rows`, use a variable:  `@rows`.  It does not need to be `DECLAREd`.

Most of the lines of the proc can be pulled out of the loop.  (However, this won't really make any difference.)

As for `ROWS` -- Most major versions and some minor versions introduce new keywords.  `ROWS` apparently was added between 5.6 and 8.0.  I avoid *some* such errors by prefixing any arguments to stored procs and declared variables in stored procs with an underscore.  This convention also helps avoid confusion between variables and column names.

Comment: thank you so much, will take care of the corrections you mentioned :)